# Could not open library 'libcurl': libcurl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am trying to execute rake db:create command. I get following error

Could not open library 'libcurl': libcurl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

```
Could not open library 'libcurl': libcurl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
Could not open library 'libcurl.so': libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 14):

- Try to install `curl`.
- If it doesn't work, try the command `ldconfig` (actualising libs)
- If it doesn't work :

  1. go to `/usr/lib`
  2. run `find . | grep curl`, locate the .so file (eg like curl_path.so or latest libcurl.so.xx)
  3. run `ln -s {curl_path.so} /usr/lib/libcurl.so`
  4. run `ldconfig`

Comment: Should "ln -s /usr/lib/libcurl.so {curl_path.so}" be "ln -s {curl_path.so} /usr/lib/libcurl.so" ?

Comment: I was running into this error when `curl` was already installed. I think it was either installed in an unexpected place or I was running into a permissions error. Regardless, I was able to fix things by running `sudo apt-get install libcurl3` which installed curl again and made things work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually - what fixed the problem was installing typhoeus:

```
gem install typhoeus
```

Or whatever package is actually needed for libcurl.